# Possible to change version numbering scheme for already deployed iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, app-store, version-numbering

Some time ago we released an app to the AppStore on a client's account. The client preferred a simple version number scheme, so the apps first version number was 1.0. Since it's release, however, there seems to be an unexpected need for minor changes to the content of the app on a regular basis, so a more precise versioning scheme, reflecting content revisions, would be more feasible now.

Is it possible to "refine" the numbering scheme in the course of an update to the app? Instead of upgrading from 1.0 to 1.1, I'd like to go to 1.0.1 now.

Would it be sufficient to just change the version number according to the new needs or will the AppStore accept only new releases if they follow the original scheme?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely can, especially if you haven't submitted the 1.1 version yet. 1.0.1 > 1.0 so it's ok.

Taken from "Developer Guide" (https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf)

Version Number:

The version number of the app you are adding. Numbering
should follow typical software versioning conventions (for
example, 1.0 or 1.0.1 or 1.1).

Comment: You're right, 1.0.1 just made it into the appstore without any problems :) Thanks!